# How to enter a key when installing into a virtual-box or other VM for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, license, license-key

Generally, how is Windows 10 run on Linux?

By which I mean, once the ISO is downloaded how is licensing dealt with?

I looked through a [guide](https://itsfoss.com/install-windows-10-virtualbox-linux/) on the process, but it didn't mention license keys.

Not sure whether I'll have a generic key, OEM, retail or other type of key.  That being said, `wmic` looks like it will return **a** key of some variety, regardless.

As the physical `UEFI` won't be available I don't see how it could possibly be installed without an actual key.

see also:

https://askubuntu.com/q/1227018/45156

Comment: In order to install Windows on a VM you must provide the license key.  If you do not have a license key you will be unable to install Windows on a VM.  You enter the same product key you would use if you installed Windows on a physical machine.  It absolutely matters if it's a retail or OEM license key.

Comment: As far as what I best understand. Window 10 installs fine on VMWare or Virtual Box. During installation initially you should select ‘I don’t have product key’ and proceed with the installation. Later after Windows 10 is fully installed connect the VM to the Internet and enter your Windows 10 License Key and activate the same. What is important here to understand is that there’s a Virtual Board with a UUID and this is used by Windows 10 to tie the license to and register the same on activation server.  Continued....

Comment: Continued... Hence if you delete the VM or copy it elsewhere then the UUID is lost or newly generated a different one and you will lose your Windows 10 activation. In case of Retail key transfer may be allowed but in case of OEM key you won’t be able to use the key again.

Comment: exactly @patkim that's what I'm trying to head-off.

Comment: As an option you can bind Windows 10 license with microsoft user account. Then I donät need any keys, just sign in deactivate old VM and activate a new one