# Can the optiplex 790 be either vertical or horizontal?

Tags: hardware-failure, desktop-computer, hardware-rec, dell-optiplex, form-factor

Not sure which of [these](https://www.dell.com/community/Desktops-General-Read-Only/Dell-optiplex-790-case-change/td-p/4213581) I have:

> ...the  Mini Tower, Desktop, Small Form Factor, or the Ultra Small
>   Form Factor

but it's probably either the mini tower or desktop.  I can say that the DVD drive is sideways, indicating, at least to me, that the system is at least capable of working horizontally.

Perhaps even preferably?

In any event, provided the system is powered off, I can't imagine it makes a difference either way??

system:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo dmidecode | grep -A3 '^System Information'
System Information
    Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
    Product Name: OptiPlex 790
    Version: 01
thufir@dur:~$
```

which is perhaps not as [new](https://superuser.com/q/1546414/55747) as I'd hoped...

Comment: If you don't need to insert a DVD/CD, the system can be in whatever orientation you desire, assuming the fans and vents are clear.

Comment: This information should be in your system manual. Otherwise the only component that really matters is the hard drive. Does your system have feet on the bottom and sides? If so then there is your answer.